# Arduino Uno Avoidance Robot: One of two motors not working

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to code an Arduino avoidance robot as a learning project. When I run the following code only one motor (the left one) works. If I comment out the if statement that uses the checkDistance() function and just loop the forward() function both motors work fine. I'm using an Adafruit Motorshield v1.2, and I believe this is the motor: [Link](http://www.evselectro.com/biaxial-dc-gear-motor--smart-car-robot-plastic-tire-wheel-gear-rate-1:48-4369). I've tried powering directly through USB, and also through external power supply (4 x AAs), and have the same issue. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
#include <AFMotor.h>
#define trigPin 3
#define echoPin 2

AF_DCMotor left_motor(2, MOTOR12_64KHZ); // create motor #1, 64KHz pwm
AF_DCMotor right_motor(1, MOTOR12_64KHZ); // motor #2\

int maxDistance = 30;
//int minDistance = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  left_motor.setSpeed(255); 
  right_motor.setSpeed(255);
}

void forward(int delayTime) { 
  left_motor.run(FORWARD);
  right_motor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(delayTime);
}

void backward(int delayTime) { 
  left_motor.run(BACKWARD);
  right_motor.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(delayTime);
}

void stop(int delayTime) {
  left_motor.run(RELEASE);
  right_motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(delayTime);
}

void right(int delayTime) {
  left_motor.run(FORWARD);
  right_motor.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(delayTime);
}

void left(int delayTime) {
  left_motor.run(BACKWARD);
  right_motor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(delayTime);
}

int checkDistance(){
  long duration, distance;
  /* The following trigPin/echoPin cycle is used to determine the
  distance of the nearest object by bouncing soundwaves off of it. */ 

  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2); 

  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 

  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  //Calculate the distance (in cm) based on the speed of sound.
  distance = duration/59.1;
  return distance;
}

void loop() {
  int currentDistance = checkDistance();
  Serial.print(currentDistance);
  if (currentDistance >= maxDistance){
    Serial.println(" cm. No immediate obstacles detected. Moving forward.");
    forward(2000);
    stop(1000);
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println(" cm. Obstacle detected. Changing direction.");
    right(1500);
    stop(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: try to more specifically identify the source of the problem. By commenting out specific lines in checkDistance() function and then loop the forward() function to see if both motors work fine. I would start with the pulseIn. Where I do not see any initial resource conflict between libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If I were trying to debug this, I would first test each of the motor functions without any logic check from the sensor. (e.g. do both wheels turn and in the correct direction when left, right, backward, etc are called just from loop()). That will give confidence that it is not a wiring or other hardware problem. If they don't work then sorting that out give you a place to start.

If they do work, then it must be the values with the sensor, right? How did you determine the `maxDistance`value? If it is too high then this line:

```
if (currentDistance >= maxDistance){
```

may never evaluate to true. You have some log statements in there so you have some sense of the value of `currentDistance`. Does it seem to be reflecting accurate values when you place objects at varying distances from the sensor?

Anyway... some thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I checked each of the functions and the motors work fine without the added logic (ie with just forward(); in the loop both motors turn forward). I also checked the serial output and it does accurately report the distance when I move my hand variable distances. Just when I use that logic block only one motor turns. Can't figure out what is causing it.

Comment: So you are saying that with the logic block, only the 'else' clause executes? Or that it executes when appropriate but the `right` function is not getting called or is not turning both motors? Also `maxDistance` - what happens if you halve that?

Comment: The if and the else clause both get executed appropriately, but forward() and right() within the statements do not work right (only one motor turns. Outside the clause if I just use forward() or right() both motors will turn.

Comment: Sample output: `41 cm. No immediate obstacles detected. Moving forward.
21 cm. Obstacle detected. Changing direction.
3 cm. Obstacle detected. Changing direction.
19 cm. Obstacle detected. Changing direction.
41 cm. No immediate obstacles detected. Moving forward.`

Comment: Well, I'm stumped - unless your `serial` calls are somehow interfering (I forget - is Arduino Rx/Tx on pins 2 & 3). Suggest you post over at the AdaFruit forums - they've been very responsive in the past.